# tokenizing text with features in specif format

Tags: python, json, dictionary, nlp, token

Hello there I am trying to create tokens with some features and arrange them in some kind of JSON format, using the following text example:

```
words = ['The study of aviation safety report in the aviation industry usually relies', 
         'The experimental results show that compared with traditional',
         'Heterogeneous Aviation Safety Cases: Integrating the Formal and the Non-formal']
```

```
{"sentence": [
           {
             indexSentence:0,
             tokens: [{
                       "indexWord": 1,
                        "word": "The",
                         "len": 3
                      },
                      { "indexWord": 2,
                        "word": "study",
                         "len": 5},
                      {"indexWord": 3,
                        "word": "of",
                         "len": 2
                       },
                       {"indexWord": 4,
                        "word": "aviation",
                         "len": 8},
                        ...
                        ]
           },
           {
            "indexSentence" : 1,
            "tokens" : [{
                        ...
                        }]
           },
           ....
         ]}
```

I trying to use the following code with no success...

```
t_d = {len(i):i for i in words}

[{'Lon' : len(t_d[i]),
  'tex' : t_d[i], 
  'Sub' : [{'index' : j,
            'token': [{
                      'word':['word: ' + j for i,j in enumerate(str(t_d[i]).split(' '))] 
                      }],
            'lenTo' : len(str(t_d[i]).split(' '))
           }
          ],
  'Sub1':[{'index' : j}]
 } for j,i in enumerate(t_d)]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution below assumes that the tokenization splits the sentence by whitespace using the `str.split` function. The solution should still be able to work with any other tokenize function.

```
from collections import defaultdict

words = ['The study of aviation safety report in the aviation industry usually relies', 
         'The experimental results show that compared with traditional',
         'Heterogeneous Aviation Safety Cases: Integrating the Formal and the Non-formal']

sentence = defaultdict(list)

for idx,i in enumerate(words):
    struct = {"indexSentence":idx,"tokens":[{"indexWord":idx_w,
                                             "word":w,
                                             "len":len(w)} for idx_w, w in enumerate(i.split())]}
    sentence['sentence'].append(struct)
    
dict(sentence)

>>
{'sentence': [{'indexSentence': 0,
   'tokens': [{'indexWord': 0, 'word': 'The', 'len': 3},
    {'indexWord': 1, 'word': 'study', 'len': 5},
    {'indexWord': 2, 'word': 'of', 'len': 2},
    {'indexWord': 3, 'word': 'aviation', 'len': 8},
    {'indexWord': 4, 'word': 'safety', 'len': 6},
    {'indexWord': 5, 'word': 'report', 'len': 6},
    {'indexWord': 6, 'word': 'in', 'len': 2},
    {'indexWord': 7, 'word': 'the', 'len': 3},
    {'indexWord': 8, 'word': 'aviation', 'len': 8},
    {'indexWord': 9, 'word': 'industry', 'len': 8},
    {'indexWord': 10, 'word': 'usually', 'len': 7},
    {'indexWord': 11, 'word': 'relies', 'len': 6}]},
  {'indexSentence': 1,
   'tokens': [{'indexWord': 0, 'word': 'The', 'len': 3},
...
}
```

You can leverage `defaultdict` to first create your list or array and then append the desired structure on top. To mimic a `json` structure you can turn in back to a `dict`.

Comment: Thank you @BernardL, this is the solution that I was trying to find. I will use this solution with several files and let you know.